# Which row's fields are returned when Grouping with MySQL?

Tags: mysql, group-by, sql-order-by

I have a MySQL table with the fields `id` and `string`.  `id`s are unique.  `string`s are varchars and are non-unique.

I perform the following query:

```
SELECT id, string, COUNT( * ) AS frequency
FROM table
GROUP BY string
ORDER BY frequency DESC, id ASC
```

**Questions**

Assume the table contains three rows with identical `string` values, and `id`s 1, 2, and 3.

1. Which `id` is going to be returned ( 1, 2, or 3 )?
2. Which `id` is this query going to `ORDER BY` ( Same as is returned? ... see question 1 )?
3. Can you control which `id` is returned / used for ordering?  eg. Return the largest `id`, or the first `id` from a GROUP.

What I'm ultimately trying to do is get a frequency occurrence for identical strings, order by that frequency, highest to lowest, and on a frequency tie, order by `id` with the smallest `id` from the group returned / ordered by.  I made the situation more generic to figure out how MySQL handles this situation.

Comment: If id is unique and you are puting it into the `select` statement, there is actually no grouping. By the way, you need to put the `id` in the group by clause too (it will show error otherwise). I suspect you wont need group by (if you explain what you really want to achieve)

Comment: Having 3 ids defeats the purpose of using ids

Comment: The query won't execute. There is a column id which is not aggregated and is not in group by.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-extensions.html

Comment: This query executes fine.  I'm trying to understand how MySQL handles this situation where the `id` returned and ordered by is ambiguous based on the SQL query.

Comment: @Kangkan Actually it will. MySQL allows that so confusing behaviour on behalf of query performance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Which id is going to be returned ( 1, 2, or 3 )?*

A: The server will choose for all the records that have the same name the id it wants (most likely the fastest to fetch, which is unpredictable). To cite the official documentation:

> The server is free to choose any value from each group, so unless they are the same, the values chosen are indeterminate.

Much more information in this [link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-extensions.html).

*Which id is this query going to ORDER BY ( Same as is returned? ... see question 1 )?*

It makes no sense to find out in what order the data retrieved will be returned as you can't predict the result you are going to get. However, it is very likely that you get the result sorted by the unpredictable ID column.

*Can you control which id is returned / used for ordering? eg. Return the largest id, or the first id from a GROUP.*

You should be assuming at this point that you can't. Read again the documentation.

Making things even more clear: You can't predict the result of an improperly used GROUP BY clause. The main issue with MySQL is that it allows you to use it in a non-standard way but you need to know how to make use of that feature. The main point behind it is to group by fields that you know will always be the same. EG:

```
SELECT id, name, COUNT( * ) AS frequency
FROM table
GROUP BY id
```

Here, you know `name` will be unique as `id` functionally determines `name`. So the result you know is valid. If you grouped also by name this query would be more standard but will perform slightly worse in MySQL.

As a final note, take into account that, in my experience the results in those non-standard queries for the selected and non-grouped fields are usually the ones that you would get applying a `GROUP BY` and then an `ORDER BY` on that field. That is why so many times it **seems** to work. However, if you keep testing you will eventually find out that this happens 95% of the time. And you can not rely on that number.

Answer (score 4):

The documentation says that when not grouping by all non-aggregate columns, one row for each unique combination if the grouped by columns is returned. The row selected is up to the server - ie "random"

However, in practice it is the first row encountered during processing. You can control which is encountered first by selecting from an inner query that is ordered in the order of preference of return.

For example to get the lowest id for each name (yes, undocumented, blah blah, but it works!):

```
SELECT id, name, COUNT( * ) AS frequency
FROM (select * from table order by id) x
GROUP BY name
ORDER BY frequency DESC, id ASC
```

I personally am comfortable relying on this behaviour and have never seen or heard of it behaving differently in real life. Many shun this as undocumented and "risky", but if it works, it works.