# Mysql Multi Group By

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a product table and it's have a product_id,
And i have other table it's have like a group.
Lets say:

```
Product table(product):
ID  NAME
1 - Shoes
2 - T-shirt
3 - apple
4 - any thing
5 - lorem ipsum
_______________________________________________
Group product table(g_product):
ID   -   GROUP ID    -   PRODUCT ID
1            1               1
2            1               2
3            1               5
```

I need a query to get just 1 product from each group.
I've tried this:

```
select * from product as p
left join g_product as g on p.id = g.fk_prod
group by group_id
```

But this bring me JUST the grouped products.

I wan't this result:

```
1 - Shoes
3 - apple
4 - any thing
```

That's the product 1 from the group 1, and the 3 and 4 haven't group.

I figure it to work with this query:

```
select * from product as p
left join g_product as g on p.id = g.fk_prod
group by g.group_id
union
select * from product as p
left join g_product as g on p.id != g.fk_prod
group by p.id
```

But this needs 30 seconds to run, and it's much. I know have a way to do this fast. But i can't figure

Comment: Why `Shoes` and not `T-Shirt` in your sample output?

Comment: Becouse shoes is the first one from grouped product, i need just one of then and when i group the products by group_id it's will bring the first right? Can be any one.

Comment: So, basically, you want to get one product from each group, plus all products that don't belong to any group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this query to fetch appropriate result

```
SELECT p.*, 
(CASE WHEN  g.gid IS NOT NULL THEN g.gid ELSE -1*p.id END) AS temp_group_id
FROM product AS p
LEFT JOIN g_product AS g ON p.id = g.fk_prod
GROUP BY temp_group_id
```

Here if a product not belong to any group then we are assigning a dummy group id (-1*p.id) to it. and that make the trick

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but i can't make this "case" works. geting this error  You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CASE
)
 as tmpgrupo

Comment: I have changed the query please test now

Comment: You should be very careful when selecting fields that are not in the group by. You will get unpredictable results. See this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18710064/which-rows-fields-are-returned-when-grouping-with-mysql/18710186#18710186) or the [official documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-extensions.html) for more information.

Comment: Thanks Mosty, I am 100% sure that above query will work. Please check with dummy data. also kindly note I have not down voted your post.

Comment: I understand that making a test might work. But if I told you that if I flip a coin a will get a head and then that happens, it doesn't mean that it will happen 100% of the time. As mentioned in the links I posted, the documentation states that the results are unpredictable (which doesn't mean they will be always wrong). In particular, see this part of the link I posted above `this is useful primarily when all values in each nonaggregated column not named in the GROUP BY are the same for each group`. This is not the case in the query you've written. I advise you to read both links

Comment: @RakeshSoni now works like a charm, =] i've tried more your solution becouse i've already thinked something like that, but don't figured the way to do it.

Comment: I think on this case it'll work, becouse its a simple situation, join both table, that products witch doesn't have a group the fk_group column will come "null", so if this column is null bring me the id(unique) else bring the group id. So that form i can group by the tmp field and it'll work fine.

Comment: @Guerra It is up to you if you want to go against the documentation. You might get any value for any of the products. EG: Product id 1 and product name for the product id 2 in the same row. I think the documentation is clear enough but as I said, it is up to you :)

Comment: @Mostly as per the document : "The server is free to choose any value from each group, so unless they are the same, the values chosen are indeterminate." ... so in above query if group id is null then we are assigning dummy and unique group id ..... but if multiple product belong to same group then you are right

Answer (score 0):

Here is my final version :)

```
select * from products
where id in (
    select p.id from products p
    left join g_product g on g.product_id = p.id
    group by g.prod_id
)
```

Note you will get ANY `p.id` if you group by without a an aggregate function such as `min(p.id)` but that will be ANY `p.id` in the `g.prod_id` group, which you've specified that was OK. If you add more than one field, such as `p.id, p.name` then you will get unpredictable results as the documentation states in this link:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-extensions.html

Comment: My product table have more then 40k products. Your query gets more then 60 seconds to run. =/

Comment: Then I bet you don't have the right indexes. 40k is quite a small number