# Mysql query group by taking wrong time stamp

Tags: php, mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

I have a query that when executed gives me the result like this

```
speciaid         | title     | date
one              | xxx       | 2013-10-03 02:13:54
one              | xxx       | 2013-10-03 03:13:54
two              | yyy       | 2013-10-02 02:13:54
```

Now if I add `GROUP BY specialid`, it gets grouped but the date i get is the old date and not the new date for the 'date' column like this

```
speciaid         | title     | date
one              | xxx       | 2013-10-03 02:13:54      // old date selected for entry one
two              | yyy       | 2013-10-02 02:13:54
```

and I want it like this

```
speciaid         | title     | date
one              | xxx       | 2013-10-03 03:13:54   // new date for entry one needed
two              | yyy       | 2013-10-02 02:13:54
```

I have tried many group by's - I get the same result. I would appreciate it very much if someone help with the group by statement for query.

Comment: You should group by all non-aggregated functions in your select clause. Otherwise the server will choose the value from the non-grouped columns that is fastest to fetch. Find more information in this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18710064/which-rows-fields-are-returned-when-grouping-with-mysql/18710186#18710186)

Comment: so how do i proceed? could u give me an example query of how i should do this

Comment: I did, but I didn't hear from you back.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for a greatest-n-per-group solution.

Usually solved this way (assuming your result is the table, due to the lack of information in the question).

Option 1:

```
SELECT * FROM t JOIN (
  SELECT title, max(`date`) `date` FROM t
  GROUP BY title
) s ON t.title = s.title AND t.`date` = s.`date`
```

Option 2:

```
SELECT t1.* FROM t t1
LEFT JOIN t t2
ON t1.title = t2.title AND t1.`date` < t2.`date`
WHERE t2.`date` IS NULL
```

Working fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/76f2d3/1

Comment: well something like this , had to edit out a lot for it to work but yea

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get first/last date from grouped column you need to use max() or min() grouped function.

```
SELECT speciaid, title, MAX(`date`) FROM table GROUP BY title;
```

Comment: As I stated in my comment in the question, this will retrieve any speciaid for a given title. `You should group by all non-aggregated functions in your select clause`

Comment: I believe that `speciaid` is the same for same titles.

Answer (score 0):

```
select speciaid, title , date
from
(select * from table_name order by date desc) d
group by title
```